# How to fix issues with comparing text of 2 files and comparing

Tags: python, python-2.7, diff

I have a script that gets the list of distribution switches from device manager "Master-EDR-List.txt".  It then grabs another txt file from a different server "New-EDR-List.txt".  Master list is pretty static until New list has additional EDRs that Master list is missing.

I would like to compare these 2 files and save any EDR that is in New list but not in Master list.  I did write a compare script but it is not reliable.  I added some additional test EDRs in New list and I am getting unexpected results based on where I place them in the list.  I always get the new ones but sometimes I also get an EDR that is in both list and sometimes I get both new EDRs in same line with no spaces.

Here is my code:

```
    old_lines = set((line.strip() for line in open('Master-EDR-List.txt', 'r+')))
    file_new = open('New-EDR-List.txt', 'r+')
    #file_diff = open('file_diff.txt', 'w')

    #Open Master File
    with open('Master-EDR-List.txt', 'r') as f:
        d = set(f.readlines())

    #Open New File
    with open('New-EDR-List.txt', 'r') as f:
        e = set(f.readlines())

    #Open Diff files to store differences
    open('file_diff.txt','w').close()

    with open('file_diff.txt', 'a') as f:
        for line in list(e - d):
            f.write(line)
```

Here are my lists I am using for testing:

Master List:

```
rts41d-an28edr1.rt.tst.com
rts41d-an28edr2.rt.tst.com
rts41d-an32edr1.rt.tst.com
rts41d-an32edr2.rt.tst.com
rts41d-as19edr1.rt.tst.com
rts41d-as19edr2.rt.tst.com
rts41d-as21edr1.rt.tst.com
rts41d-as21edr2.rt.tst.com
rts12a-ah46edr2.rt.tst.com
rts12a-al46edr2.rt.tst.com
rts12a-as46edr1.rt.tst.com
rts12a-as46edr2.rt.tst.com
rts12a-as46edr2.rt.tst.com
rts12a-aw46edr1.rt.tst.com
rts12a-aw46edr2.rt.tst.com
rts12a-aw46edr2.rt.tst.com
rts12b-as46edr1.rt.tst.com
rts12b-ax46edr1.rt.tst.com
```

New List:

```
rts41d-an28edr1.rt.tst.com
rts41d-an28edr2.rt.tst.com
rts41d-an32edr1.rt.tst.com
rts41d-an32edr2.rt.tst.com
rts41d-as19edr1.rt.tst.com
rts41d-as19edr2.rt.tst.com
rt511-sps5.rt.tst.com
rts41d-as21edr1.rt.tst.com
rts41d-as21edr2.rt.tst.com
rts12a-ah46edr2.rt.tst.com
rts12a-al46edr2.rt.tst.com
rts12a-as46edr1.rt.tst.com
rts12a-as46edr2.rt.tst.com
rt511-sps6.rt.tst.com
rts12a-as46edr2.rt.tst.com
rts12a-aw46edr1.rt.tst.com
rts12a-aw46edr2.rt.tst.com
rts12a-aw46edr2.rt.tst.com
rts12b-as46edr1.rt.tst.com
rts12b-ax46edr1.rt.tst.com
rt511-sps7.rt.tst.com
```

I added 2 test rt511-sps5, 6 and 7 in the list and instead of only getting these 3 item, I am getting this in my Diff file:

Diff File:

```
rt511-sps7.rt.tst.comrt511-sps5.rt.tst.com
rt511-sps6.rt.tst.com
rts12b-ax46edr1.rt.tst.com
```

As you can see, sps7 and 5 are in same line for some reason and "rts12b-ax46edr1" should not be there as it is already in both files.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?  New List can discover any new distribution switch and put it anywhere on list depending on its name.  I would like this script to only print out any new EDR in the list that Master does not have.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your script. Please use the below code to fulfil your requirement. Do not forget to close all the open files.

```
with open('Master-EDR-List.txt', 'r') as f:
 d = f.readlines()
#Open New File
with open('New-EDR-List.txt', 'r') as f:
 e = f.readlines()
out = open('file_diff.txt', 'a')

for newline in e:
 found = False
 for oldline in d:
  if((newline.strip(' \t\n\r')) == (oldline.strip(' \t\n\r'))):
   found = True
   break;
 if(found == False):
  if(newline != '\n'):
   out.writelines(newline)
```

Comment: It did fix the first line and added them into separate file but I am still seeing same output.  rts12b-ax46edr1.rt.tst.com is still in list even though it exists in both file.  I am not sure why its doing this.

Comment: I think I found the issue.  I debug the loop and went thru all the iterations until I reach last one.  Here is what it is doing.  NewLine = 'rts12b-ax46edr1.rt.tst.com\n" while old_line = "rts12b-ax46edr1.rt.tst.com".  Since on Master file it is the last item, it does not have "\n" at the end.  Is there anyway I can remove "\n" for being used in comparison and instead use names only?

Comment: @Neo I have modified the code now it should work as per your requirement. Please let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: that worked perfectly.... Thx.  The only issue I am having is it is not over-writing "file_diff.txt" but everything I run the script, it keeps adding same item to it.  It should over-write with new item every time.  I believe it is that 'a' under open file line but I tried w and r and it is not working.